# copying files in python with check for duplicates

Tags: python, recursion, copy, duplicates, shutil

I'm new to this python and trying to write a program to recursively copy jpgs in a folder structure to a new folder, and to change the filename if their is a duplicate filename.

```
srcDir = 'Users/photos/2008/thumbnails/' #files in two more dir deep 
toDir = 'Users/external_drive/2008/'

shutil.copy(srcDir,toDir)
if filename = filename
    filename + '_2.jpg'
```

Comment: Check if the file exists before copying the new one. If yes, then choose another name.

Comment: Have you taken the time to work your way through [The Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)?

Comment: i didn't know about the tut. i will now. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should do what you need. It uses `os.walk` to recurse through all of your folders looking for files with a `.jpg` extension. If a filename already exists in the `toDir`, it keeps incrementing a file counter until an empty slot is found and it displays a log of all the copies as it goes:

```
import os, shutil

srcDir = 'Users/photos/2008/thumbnails/' #files in two more dir deep 
toDir = 'Users/external_drive/2008/'

try:
    os.makedirs(toDir)
except:
    pass

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(srcDir, topdown=True):
    for file in files:
        src = os.path.join(root, file)
        target = os.path.join(toDir, file)

        if file.lower().endswith('.jpg'):
            index = 1

            while os.path.exists(target):
                index +=1
                target = os.path.join(toDir, os.path.splitext(file)[0]+ "_%d.jpg" % index)

            print "Copying: '%s'  to  '%s'" % (src, target)
            shutil.copy(src, target)
```

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to accept one of the answers when you are ready, to collect your Scholar badge.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there are some errors in your code:

- `=` is an assignment in python; `==` checks for equality
- `shutil.copy()` expects a file, not a directory, as source

For traversing a directory tree in python you can take a look at this nice [tutorial](http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-traverse-a-directory-tree-in-python-guide-to-os-walk/).

For checking if a file exists have a look at this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python).